# Comparing characters in a string

Tags: python, string, list

Given two strings as parameters return true iff the first word can be formed from the second word by changing exactly one letter. The way I approached this is:

```
def differ(word_one, word_two):
    '''(str, str) -> bool

    Returns true iff word_two can be formed from word_one by changing
    exactly one letter.

    >>> differ('cat', 'bat')
    True
    >>> differ('word', 'sword')
    False

    '''
    temp_list = []
    # If the length of the first string is equal to the length of the
    # second string, iterate over the letters in the first string and
    # if the letter in the first string does not equal to the letter 
    # in the second string append the letter to temp_list
    if len(word_one) == len(word_two):
        for char in word_one:
            if char != word_two[word_one.index(char)]:
                temp_list.append(char)
    if len(temp_list) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My code seems to be working fine according to the description but is there a more simplified approach to this?

Comment: Your use of `word_one.index(char)` will have problems if `word_one` has repeated letters. For example, `abracadabra` and `abrzczdzbrz` would falsely say no letters have changed.

Comment: fyi: this is a subset of the [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) problem.

Comment: If this isn't just for an exercise, don't reinvent the wheel - reuse the already existing code in `difflib`

Comment: Also, why did you put in `//` "comments".  Certainly they're not in your actual code -- if they were, it wouldn't have ran ;-).  Why not just use regular python `#` comments?  That would make it much easier to copy/paste your code and run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if len(word_one) == len(word_two):
    return sum(c!=d for c,d in zip(word_one, word_two)) == 1
return False   # optional - often None will do instead
```

Another way using map.

```
import operator
def differ(w1, w2):
    return len(w1) == len(w2) and sum(map(operator.ne, w1, w2)) == 1
```

The problem with the versions using `sum` is that they iterate the whole strings even if there are a couple of differences already at the start. So there is a shortcircuiting version

```
import operator, itertools
def differ(w1, w2):
    it = itertools.imap(operator.ne, w1, w2)
    return len(w1) == len(w2) and any(it) and not any(it)
```

Comment: Note also that on python3.x, `map` picked up the shorter series truncating behavior of `zip`.

Comment: @mgilson, Obviously more coffee is required. Yes imap does that too.

Comment: @mgilson, can you check the shortcircuiting version for me while i get coffee?

Comment: Short circuiting looks good to me.  Still not terribly used to that `any` trick (although I get how it works).

Comment: That said, I think that we decided that the first `map` version is no good.  It give a false `True` for `"hat"` and `"hats"` since on python2.x, `None != "s"` is `True`, so you still need the explicit length checking.

Comment: @mgilson, good point. It sure doesn't match the behaviour of the original function in that regard. I think I would always check the length first in "real" code anyway

Answer (score 5):

seems like a simple `zip` (plus some length checking), no?

```
sum(a != b for a, b in zip(word1, word2)) == 1
```

This does rely on the somewhat obscure fact that in arithmetic contexts, 
`True == 1` and `False == 0`.  e.g. `True + True + True + False == 3`

example:

```
>>> def differ(word1, word2):
...     return ((len(word1) == len(word2)) and 
...             (sum(a != b for a, b in zip(word1, word2)) == 1))
... 
>>> differ('cat', 'bat')
True
>>> differ('cat', 'hat')
True
>>> differ('cat', 'can')
True
>>> differ('cat', 'car')
True
>>> differ('cat', 'bar')
False
```

Comment: You also need to check that the words are the same length.

Comment: Don't forget zip stops at the end of the shortest string

Comment: `izip_longest` wouldn't work properly. It would return true for "abc" and "abcd".